# Is there a way to categorize days and month into if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, categories

Rules for the seasons in the Northern Hemisphere

[image]

I am not sure how to add 01,02,03,04 months as winters and rest as their respective seasons. I am aware that we have to use if statements, but I want to know if we can categorize them.

Comment: The rules are off a bit from the seasons, but yes, you're going to have to code a series of if conditions to determine the season.  One easy thing you can do is create a String array to hold 12 seasons, Winter in the first three positions, Spring in the next three, and so on.  Yoiu can do the first part by subtracting one from the month and getting the season from the String array.

Comment: Why March belongs to winter and December belongs to Fall/Autumn?

Answer (score 2):

To add an answer to @user9596600

This looks like a case for switch statements! (Yes I have read the exercise but I still think this is good to know) If you don't know what they are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is a great example with mapping a number to a month. This uses the "old" switch expression. But since java 12 you are able to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) new syntax which looks a lot cleaner

We will proceed just as written in the exercise. First figure out the month and set the season accordingly after which we will calculate if the day has passed into the next season.

#### Part 1:

I'll just assume your method declaration is
`private String getSeason(int month, int day)`
and that `season` will be the variable to return.
An example switch statement could look as followed

```java
switch (month) {
    case 1, 2, 3 -> season = "Winter";
    case 4, 5, 6 -> season = "Spring";
    case 7, 8, 9 -> season = "Summer";
    case 10, 11, 12 -> season = "Fall";
    default -> season = "No season at all >:(";
}
```

As you saw, you can "categorize" months into their appropriate season. Now onto

#### Part 2:

You are also able to use switch statements on `String` objects. To do that

```java
if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
    switch (season) {
        case "Winter" -> season = "Spring";
        case "Spring" -> season = "Summer";
        case "Summer" -> season = "Fall";
        case "Fall" -> season = "Winter";
    }
}
```

So in the end you'd have a clean and neat solution looking something like this

```java
private String getSeason(int month, int day) {
    String season;

    switch (month) {
        case 1, 2, 3 -> season = "Winter";
        case 4, 5, 6 -> season = "Spring";
        case 7, 8, 9 -> season = "Summer";
        case 10, 11, 12 -> season = "Fall";
        default -> season = "No season at all >:(";
    }

    if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
        switch (season) {
            case "Winter" -> season = "Spring";
            case "Spring" -> season = "Summer";
            case "Summer" -> season = "Fall";
            case "Fall" -> season = "Winter";
        }
    }

    return season;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since seasons are a bit shifted here, an array of strings could be used and `seasonId` should be calculated according to the mentioned rules:

```java
public static String[] seasons = {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"};

public static String getSeason(int month, int day) {
    int seasonId = (month - 1) / 3 % seasons.length;

    if (day >= 21 && month % 3 == 0) {
        seasonId = (seasonId + 1) % seasons.length;
    }
    return seasons[seasonId];
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(" 3/23 -> " + getSeason(3, 23));
System.out.println(" 6/01 -> " + getSeason(6, 1));
System.out.println(" 6/28 -> " + getSeason(6, 28));
System.out.println(" 9/21 -> " + getSeason(9, 21));
System.out.println("12/20 -> " + getSeason(12, 20));
System.out.println("12/25 -> " + getSeason(12, 25));
```

Output:

```
 3/23 -> Spring
 6/01 -> Spring
 6/28 -> Summer
 9/21 -> Fall
12/20 -> Fall
12/25 -> Winter
```

---

Following comment by @user16320675, a version with Java 12+ `switch` statement may look like this:

```java
public static String getSeason(int month, int day) {
    return switch(month) {
        case 1, 2 -> "Winter";
        case 3 -> day < 21 ? "Winter" : "Spring";
        case 4, 5 -> "Spring";
        case 6 -> day < 21 ? "Spring" : "Summer";
        case 7, 8 -> "Summer";
        case 9 -> day < 21 ? "Summer" : "Fall";
        case 10, 11 -> "Fall";
        case 12 -> day < 21 ? "Fall" : "Winter";
        default -> "Season undefined for bad month: " + month;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `if` or `switch` at all.
Actually it is easier by doing some integer division and modulo.

```
public static String[] seasons = {"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"};

public static String getSeason(int month, int day) {
    int d = 30 * month + day - 21;  // days since winter begin
    int seasonId = d / 90 % 4;
    return seasons[seasonId];
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(" 3/20 -> " + getSeason(3, 20));
System.out.println(" 3/21 -> " + getSeason(3, 21));
System.out.println(" 6/20 -> " + getSeason(6, 20));
System.out.println(" 6/21 -> " + getSeason(6, 21));
System.out.println(" 9/20 -> " + getSeason(9, 20));
System.out.println(" 9/21 -> " + getSeason(9, 21));
System.out.println("12/20 -> " + getSeason(12, 20));
System.out.println("12/21 -> " + getSeason(12, 21));
```

Output:

```
 3/20 -> Winter
 3/21 -> Spring
 6/20 -> Spring
 6/21 -> Summer
 9/20 -> Summer
 9/21 -> Fall
12/20 -> Fall
12/21 -> Winter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```java
if (1 <= month && month <= 3) { season = "Winter"; }
else if (4 <= month && month <= 6) { season = "Spring"; }
else if (7 <= month && month <= 9) { season = "Summer"; }
else if (10 <= month && month <= 12) { season = "Fall"; }
else { throw new RuntimeException("unexpected month"); }

if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
    if (season.equals("Winter") { season = "Spring"; }
    else if (season.equals("Spring") { season = "Summer"; }
    else if (season.equals("Summer") { season = "Fall"; }
    else { season = "Winter"; }
}
```

What do you mean by categorizing IF statements? You could nest them like this:

```java
if (1 <= month && month <= 3) { 
   if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
       season = 'Winter';
   } else {
       season = 'Spring';
   }
else if (4 <= month && month <= 6) {
   if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
       season = 'Summer';
   } else {
       season = 'Spring';
   }
} 
// etc ...
```

Comment: The question is marked as `java` not `python`

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary: Thank goodness.  I was wondering if I was seeing Java 17.  :-)